# Transformation of function (translation and stretches)

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

Suppose that we are given the function $f(x)$ and $g(x)= f(x+3)$, then what is $g(\frac{x}{2})$ ? Is it equal to $f(\frac{x+3}{2})$  or $f(\frac{x}{2} +3)$ ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$g(z)=f(z+3)$$

That is if the input of $g$ is $z$, it is going to be evaluated to $f(z+3)$.

Here, $z= \frac{x}{2}$

Hence we get $$f\left( \frac{x}2+3 \right)$$

Answer (score 1):

You simply substitute $x$ with $\frac{x}{2}$. So it's $f(\frac{x}{2}+3)$.

Comment: Conversely, let $y$ be $x+3$. Then $f(y)$ is $g(y-3)$. So $f(\frac{x+3}{2})$ is $g(\frac{x+3}{2}-3)$.

Answer (score 0):

Since $g(x)=f(x+3)$ then $g(\frac{x}{2})=f(\frac{x}{2}+3)$